# Android Expandable listview in a tabhost

Tags: android, tabs, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I want to to implement `ExpandableListView` under `TabHost`...tab works well and list also generate but when i go to `ExpandList` clicking on `GroupItem`, the application unexpectedly stop...

how can i implement this...

my code is here....

**Setting.java**

```
public class Setting extends Fragment {

    ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
    ExpandableListView expListView;
    List<String> listDataHeader;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;


    @Override
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.setting, null);
     expListView = (ExpandableListView) v.findViewById(R.id.lvExp);

        prepareListData();       

     // preparing list data
    // 

     listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(getActivity(), listDataHeader, listDataChild);

     // setting list adapter
     expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);


     expListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {

         @Override
         public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                 int groupPosition, long id) {
             // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
             // "Group Clicked " + listDataHeader.get(groupPosition),
             // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             return false;
         }
     });

     // Listview Group expanded listener
     expListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {

         @Override
         public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
             Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                     listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Expanded",
                     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }
     });

     // Listview Group collasped listener
     expListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new OnGroupCollapseListener() {

         @Override
         public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
             Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                     listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Collapsed",
                     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

         }
     });

     // Listview on child click listener
     expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

         @Override
         public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                 int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             Toast.makeText(
                     getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                     listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " : "+ listDataChild.get(listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(
                                     childPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


             return false;
         }
     });



     return v;
     }


    private void prepareListData() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
        listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

        // Adding child data
        listDataHeader.add("Battery Remaining");
        listDataHeader.add("Set Alarm Distance");
        listDataHeader.add("Set Alarm Tone");

        // Adding child data
        List<String> top250 = new ArrayList<String>();
        top250.add("The Shawshank Redemption");
        top250.add("The Godfather");
        top250.add("The Godfather: Part II");
        top250.add("Pulp Fiction");
        top250.add("The Good, the Bad and the Ugly");
        top250.add("The Dark Knight");
        top250.add("12 Angry Men");

        List<String> nowShowing = new ArrayList<String>();
        nowShowing.add("The Conjuring");
        nowShowing.add("Despicable Me 2");
        nowShowing.add("Turbo");
        nowShowing.add("Grown Ups 2");
        nowShowing.add("Red 2");
        nowShowing.add("The Wolverine");

        List<String> comingSoon = new ArrayList<String>();
        comingSoon.add("2 Guns");
        comingSoon.add("The Smurfs 2");
        comingSoon.add("The Spectacular Now");
        comingSoon.add("The Canyons");
        comingSoon.add("Europa Report");

        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), top250); // Header, Child data
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), nowShowing);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), comingSoon);
    }
```

**ExpandableListAdapter:**

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

     private Context _context;
        private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
        // child data in format of header title, child title
        private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

        public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
                HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
            this._context = context;
            this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
            this._listDataChild = listChildData;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
            return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                    .get(childPosititon);
        }

        @Override
        public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return childPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.child_battery, null);
            }

            TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.battery);

            txtListChild.setText(childText);
            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
            return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                    .size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
            return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
        }

        @Override
        public int getGroupCount() {
            return this._listDataHeader.size();
        }

        @Override
        public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
            return groupPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.parent, null);
            }

            TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
            lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasStableIds() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return true;
        }

}
}
```

Comment: logcat.....02-25 17:40:14.172: E/Trace(29308): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)

Comment: please add all error logcat to your question

Comment: sorry now i press on parent but not response...plz help me...

Comment: Please post your Logcat complete error

Comment: there is no msg on logcat....